# The number of permutations that can commute with the element induced by subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, finite-groups

It’s a problem form Jacobson’s book “Basic Algebra II” Ch.1

> Let $G$ be a finite group, $H$ a subgroup. Show that the number of permutations of $G$ that commute with every $h_L$, $h\in H$ (acting in $G$), is $$[G:H]!\lvert H\rvert^{[G:H]},$$ where $[G:H]$ is the index of $H$ in $G$.

Note: $h_L\in {\rm Sym}\; G$ means that $h_L:x\mapsto hx$.

I just know that any $a_R$($a\in G$) can commute with $h_L$,but I don’t know other elements in ${\rm Sym}\; G$ that can commute with $h_L$.

Besides, this problem belongs to the section “Some Basic Categorical Concepts”. I don’t know how can it connect with Category.

Comment: What is $h_L$ and $a_R$ ?

Comment: @ΓιάννηςΠαπαβασιλείου Sorry,I have rewritten the problem

Comment: In brief - the action of $H$ by multiplication on the elements of $G$ gives $|G:H|$ orbits each of size $|H|$. If we restrict to one of these orbits, we find $|H|$ permutations of that orbit commuting with all elements of that orbit. Since there $|G:H|$ orbits, we get $|H|^{|G:H|}$ centralizing elements like this. But we can also permute the orbits in any way we like, giving a total of $|G:H|!|H|^{|G:H|}$ centralizing elements.

Comment: @DerekHolt Sorry，I don‘t know your second sentence.Can you explain it in more details？Thank you！

Comment: I think you do know it, because this follows from what you wrote yourself: "I just know that any $a_R\,(a \in G)$ can commute with $h_L$". If we apply this statement to an individual orbit of $H$, then we find that the elements $a_R$ with $a \in H$  commute with all elements of $H$ on that orbit. This can be applied to each of the $|G:H|$ orbits independently, giving $|H|^{|G:H|}$ elements that commute with $H$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I get it！Thank you very much！

Comment: @DerekHolt What do you mean by permutations that commute with elements of the orbits? Aren't the orbits effectively the right cosets of $H$? Thus, what does it mean to say a permutation commutes with group elements? In the counting argument, why do we also restrict ourselves to looking at permutations of specific orbits? For example, what rules out a permutation of SymG whose restriction to an orbit is not a permutation of that orbit? Thank you!

Comment: @Wilson Yes the orbits are the right cosets $Hg$. For a fixed orbit $Hg$, I meant those permutations $\tau$ of $Hg$ that commute with the action of every element of $H$ on $Hg$; that is, $h\tau(\alpha) = \tau h (\alpha)$ for all $h \in H$ and $\alpha \in Hg$. For your second question, any permutation that centralizes (or even normalizes) every element of $H$ must permute the orbits of $H$. That is, the orbits of $H$ form a system of blocks of imprimitivity for $N_{\rm Sym}(G)(H)$.